# Using API.AI event triggers with Telegram Chat bot

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es, telegram-webhook

I'm using a node server to trigger an event for an API.AI intent that kicks off a series of questions to a Telegram User. Once the trigger is initiated, the questionnaire doesn't begin until a user directly sends some message from Telegram to the bot. Has anyone had any experience with this? I would ideally like API.AI to commence the questionnaire the moment the trigger hits. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Has your Telegram user started your bot yet? If yes then you shouldn't have any problems sending messages to him at any time.

Comment: Yes. On the response of that event trigger, i get back the response that should go out to the bot. so my temporary fix is to grab the response and directly send a message from the server through Telegram's API bypassing API.AI.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting it right but I think you have a problem with pushing your messages to telegram users. I'm using [telebot](https://github.com/mullwar/telebot) and there is [this](https://github.com/mullwar/telebot#sendmessagechat_id-text-parsemode-replytomessage-replymarkup-notification-webpreview) `sendMessage` method which can be used to send any messages to any known TelegramID. Maybe you are not storing TelegramIDs.

Comment: That's the go to method if you are accessing the Telegram API directly, but I am trying to do it through API.AI where this limitation is in place.